# Windows DLL user space calling process

Tags: windows, dll, loadlibrary, loadmodule

I'm trying to understand how Windows recursively loads DLLs in user space.

Tracing `kernel32.ReadProcessMemory` as an example:

The first step for `ReadProcessMemory` is the IAT of `kernel32`:

`00007FF901F6AFA0 | 48:FF25 21D20500         | jmp qword ptr ds:[<&ReadProcessMemory>] |`

Which `jmp`'s to `kernelbase.ReadProcessMemory`:

```
00007FF9002D22F0 | 48:83EC 48               | sub rsp,48                                   |
00007FF9002D22F4 | 48:8D4424 30             | lea rax,qword ptr ss:[rsp+30]                |
00007FF9002D22F9 | 48:894424 20             | mov qword ptr ss:[rsp+20],rax                |
00007FF9002D22FE | 48:FF15 C3521400         | call qword ptr ds:[<&ZwReadVirtualMemory>]   |
<snip>
```

Which `call`'s `ntdll.ZwReadVirtualMemory`:

```
00007FF902F5C840 | 4C:8BD1                  | mov r10,rcx                                  |
00007FF902F5C843 | B8 3F000000              | mov eax,3F                                   | 3F:'?'
00007FF902F5C848 | F60425 0803FE7F 01       | test byte ptr ds:[7FFE0308],1                |
00007FF902F5C850 | 75 03                    | jne ntdll.7FF902F5C855                       |
00007FF902F5C852 | 0F05                     | syscall                                      |
00007FF902F5C854 | C3                       | ret                                          |
00007FF902F5C855 | CD 2E                    | int 2E                                       |
00007FF902F5C857 | C3                       | ret                                          |
```

So the flow from user mode in this example is:

1. `kernel32.ReadProcessMemory`
2. `kernelbase.ReadProcessMemory`
3. `ntdll.ZwReadVirtualMemory`

The expectation would be that each of the above DLLs can 'find' the appropriate function based on their IAT/imported functions from other DLLs when they are loaded.

Using `dumpbin` and tracing the `IMPORTS` this is true for `kernel32.ReadProcessMemory` (where `api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll` is an `ApiSet` for `kernelbase.dll`):

```
    api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
             180078178 Import Address Table
             18009E120 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                          35 VirtualQueryEx
                          <snip>
                          1C ReadProcessMemory
```

However, this is not true for `kernelbase.dll` - `NtReadVirtualMemory` is imported, however `ZwReadVirtualMemory` is not imported:

```
    ntdll.dll
             1801A67C8 Import Address Table
             180262A48 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                         893 __C_specific_handler
                         <snip>
                         205 NtReadVirtualMemory
```

So, my question is: during the DLL load process, how does `kernelbase.dll` identify the 'location' of `ZwReadVirtualMemory` if it isn't imported?

The `ZwReadVirtualMemory` function is being called by `kernelbase.dll`, so it must have been resolved/stored in the IAT at some point, but how does this happen technically?

Is there some indirection where the loader maps `NtReadVirtualMemory` to `ZwReadVirtualMemory` as [these functions resolve to the same address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-nt-and-zw-versions-of-the-native-system-services-routines)?

Comment: The disassembler has to choose a name for the address. There are two names, and it just picks one. Apparently, it picked the one that confused you. It could just have easily have chosen `NtReadVirtualMemory` and then you presumably wouldn't have been confused.